# XMl parse in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, sqlxml

I have this xml structure.I use the following  sql to read the values but it doesnt work

```
DECLARE @x XML =
'<Events>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="25/10/2013 18:45:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="England - Championship" LeagueID="10099" ID="5693075" IsOption="0" EventType="0" MEID="2673883">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Middlesbrough" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Doncaster" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <MoneyLine Home="1.69" Draw="3.7" Away="5" />
    <Spread Home_Odds="1.885" Home_Points="-0.75" Away_Points="0.75" Away_Odds="1.962" />
    <Total Points="2.75" Over="2.06" Under="1.763" />
  </Event>
  <Event DateTimeGMT="25/10/2013 18:45:00" Branch="Soccer" Sport="Soccer" BranchID="1" League="England - Championship" LeagueID="10099" ID="5693993" IsOption="1" EventType="200" MEID="2673883">
    <Participants>
      <Participant1 Name="Middlesbrough" Home_Visiting="Home" />
      <Participant2 Name="Doncaster" Home_Visiting="Visiting" />
    </Participants>
    <Total Points="4.5" Over="5.75" Under="1.125" />
  </Event>
</Events>
'
DECLARE @iDoc INT
EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML(@iDoc,'/Events/Event')
WITH    (
ID int '@ID',
DateTimeGMT [varchar](100) '@DateTimeGMT',
Branch [varchar](100) '@Branch',
Sport [varchar](100) '@Sport',
BranchID int '@BranchID',
League [varchar](100) '@League',
LeagueID int '@LeagueID',
IsOption int '@IsOption',
EventType int '@EventType',
MEID int '@MEID',
QAID int '@QAID',
EventName [varchar](500) '@EventName',
Home [varchar](100) '../Event/Participants/Participant1/@Name',
Away [varchar](100) '../Event/Participants/Participant2/@Name',
[1] [varchar](5) '../Event/MoneyLine/@Home',
[X] [varchar](5) '../Event/MoneyLine/@Draw',
[2] [varchar](5) '../Event/MoneyLine/@Away',
Spread_Home_Points float '../Event/Spread/@Home_Points',
Spread_Home_Odds float '../Event/Spread/@Home_Odds',
Spread_Away_Points float '../Event/Spread/@Away_Points',
Spread_Away_Odds float '../Event/Spread/@Away_Odds',
Total_Points float '../Event/Total/@Points',
Lart float '../Event/Total/@Over',
Posht float '../Event/Total/@Under'
        )

EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @iDoc
```

But this doent give a correct answer. On the second row that doesnt fine MoneyLine it repeats the first row values.
[image]

The values marked with circle showld be empty.Any help please?

Comment: can you make the output readable/view-able/larger?

Comment: I croped a bit the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use nodes() method for reading xml in SQL server, it's much easier to use. For your XML it could be something like this:

```
select
    T.C.value('@DateTimeGMT', 'varchar(100)') as DateTimeGMT,
    T.C.value('@Branch', 'varchar(100)') as Branch,
    T.C.value('@BranchID', 'int') as BranchID,
    T.C.value('@League', 'varchar(100)') as League,
    T.C.value('@LeagueID', 'int') as LeagueID,
    T.C.value('@IsOption', 'int') as IsOption,
    T.C.value('@EventType', 'int') as EventType,
    T.C.value('@MEID', 'int') as MEID,
    T.C.value('@QAID', 'int') as QAID,
    T.C.value('@EventName', 'varchar(500)') as EventName,
    T.C.value('(Participants/Participant1)[1]/@Name', 'varchar(100)') as Home,
    T.C.value('(Participants/Participant2)[1]/@Name', 'varchar(100)') as Away,
    T.C.value('(MoneyLine)[1]/@Home', 'varchar(5)') as [1],
    T.C.value('(MoneyLine)[1]/@Draw', 'varchar(5)') as [X],
    T.C.value('(MoneyLine)[1]/@Away', 'varchar(5)') as [2],
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Home_Points', 'float') as Spread_Home_Points,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Home_Odds', 'float') as Spread_Home_Odds,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Away_Points', 'float') as Spread_Away_Points,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Away_Odds', 'float') as Spread_Away_Odds,
    T.C.value('(Spread)[1]/@Away_Odds', 'float') as Spread_Away_Odds,
    T.C.value('(Total)[1]/@Points', 'float') as Total_Points,
    T.C.value('(Total)[1]/@Over', 'float') as Lart,
    T.C.value('(Total)[1]/@Under', 'float') as Posht
from @x.nodes('Events/Event') as T(C)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23601)</kbd>**

To get data from element filtered by attribute, you can use xpath:

```
select
    T.C.value('(Participants/Participant[@Name="Odd"]/Odds)[1]/@OddsValue', 'float') as Odd,
    T.C.value('(Participants/Participant[@Name="Even"]/Odds)[1]/@OddsValue', 'float') as Even
from @x.nodes('Events/Event') as T(C)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23614)</kbd>**

Comment: Yes this works ok but if you see my second answer when i add a different node i cannot get all the parameters there. Please check my second answer

Comment: @user1361208 dont' know what exactly you want. Updated answer to show how can you filter xml by attribute value. Answered your other question with another way of parsing - all participants to the rows

Answer (score 3):

The XPath expressions you are using are not matching the `Event` element you are after. Considering only the `1`, `X` and `2` columns, their XPath expressions should be:

```
[1] [varchar](5) 'MoneyLine/@Home',
[X] [varchar](5) 'MoneyLine/@Draw',
[2] [varchar](5) 'MoneyLine/@Away',
```

This way, they will be relative to the `Event` element you are considering. With your original expressions, they pointed to the first `Event` element of the parent of the row being processed and this is why they behaved wrongly. The same considerations apply for every other expression in your block of code starting with `../Event`.

Comment: Can you help with my new xml?

Answer (score 0):

Apart of Efran's answer (+1) I would use `nodes` and `value` methods ([ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx))  to query XML:

```
SELECT  x.XmlCol.value('(@ID)[1]', 'INT') AS [ID],
        x.XmlCol.value('(@DateTimeGMT)[1]', '[varchar](100)') AS [DateTimeGMT],
        x.XmlCol.value('(Sport)[1]', '[varchar](100)') AS [Sport],
        -- ...
        x.XmlCol.value('(Participants/Participant1/@Name)[1]', '[varchar](100)') AS [Home],
        x.XmlCol.value('(Participants/Participant2/@Name)[1]', '[varchar](100)') AS [Away],
        -- ...
        x.XmlCol.value('(MoneyLine/@Home)[1]', '[varchar](5)') AS [1],
        x.XmlCol.value('(MoneyLine/@Draw)[1]', '[varchar](5)') AS [X],
        x.XmlCol.value('(MoneyLine/@Away)[1]', '[varchar](5)') AS [2]
FROM    @x.nodes('/Events/Event') x(XmlCol);
```